# GNOME Super key - show windows / overview (toggle-overview)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

GNOME Shell 44.3

When I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (<kbd>❖</kbd> ) I would like to get the „overview“ view. I.e. all open windows in a grid. This used to be, but not in this version.

I can do <kbd>Super+S</kbd> to get a similar overview. I never use the "apps" things + I do not like the workspace at top but that is another story. Further the current view by pressing this key is not anything I use.

I tried to set <kbd>Super</kbd> key by [Set Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA8W6.png) to Super. Nothing happens. It does not recognize that as a key. Then I looked into `dconf` and found that:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.mutter overlay-key
'Super_L'
```

I removed that and tried to set `toggle-overview` to Super by various values:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview
['<Super>s']
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview Super_L
expected value:
  Super_L
  ^
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview "['<Super>']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview "['<Super_L>']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview ...
```

but does not work. In addition the GUI variant the *Show the overview* as Disabled when set to for example `"['<Super_L>']"`: [Show the overview ~ disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVYiG.png)

Is there a way to set <kbd>Super</kbd> to `toggle-overview`?